# C++ project layout

Tags: c++, oop, layout

I am completely confused as to the proper way to layout a C++ project.

I had all my classes in separate .cpp files, with their definitions in .h files. I then had one "header.h" which contained all the class headers, external dependencies and a few other things. But I wasn't able to use class names in the header files, where I needed to declare a pointer to one.

Can someone please explain the proper object-orientated layout for a C++ project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix the problem "wasn't able to use class names in the header files, where I needed to declare a pointer to one" by using [forward class declarations](http://www-subatech.in2p3.fr/~photons/subatech/soft/carnac/CPP-INC-1.shtml), like:

```
class myClass;
```

However, having every class include a header.h that then includes *every class* is overkill.  Instead, you should have each class specifically include only the classes and external dependencies that it actually needs.

Comment: Good point, although (not clear from the question), you could decide to have 1 external header to your module that could be included by dependent modules.

Comment: This is precisely what I was doing wrong, thanks for the quick answer. I'll accept soon if no-one comes up with a better answer.